# In Objective C what does the "^{ ... }" mean?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I keep seeing lines of code with `^{ some code }` in it...  I thought that maybe it allowed to run a function inline similar to a lambda function.  But I can not find any documentation on it.  Could someone please enlighten me?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html

Comment: Not trying to sound rude or anything... but if you google "objective c lambda function" you literally get what it is in the top 5 results

Comment: Of course knowing that it's called a "lambda" (or even a block) is 99% of the battle.

Comment: googling for Objective-C and lambda would have brought you possibly here: http://www.xs-labs.com/en/archives/articles/objc-blocks/

Comment: When I saw the syntax was different for lambda then what I have been seeing I was not sure if they were the same...

Comment: Just make sure that if you question was answered, you make sure to mark the person who answered it, otherwise it looks like you still need help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a block.

See the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html).

Answer (score 3):

Tis a block!

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH7-SW1

To steal Apple's example:

```
int multiplier = 7;
int (^myBlock)(int) = ^(int num) {
    return num * multiplier;
};

printf("%d", myBlock(3));
// prints "21"
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a block indeed...

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/9328/creating-a-diner-app-using-blocks-part-1) for people who are beginners to blocks!

Answer (score 1):

As Apple states in [their documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH7-SW1):

> You use the ^ operator to declare a block variable and to indicate the
>   beginning of a block literal. The body of the block itself is
>   contained within {}, as shown in this example (as usual with C, ;
>   indicates the end of the statement):
>
> ```
> int multiplier = 7;
> int (^myBlock)(int) = ^(int num) {
>     return num * multiplier;
> };
> ```

Comment: Always make sure you properly quote language copied from documentation.